# Gcd(X,Y) in rings of polynomials in two variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Say $k$ is a UFD and consider $k[X,Y].$ What is $gcd(X,Y) $ in this ring ? My first intuition was 1 but this cannot be true because then $(X,Y)$ would be the whole ring but I’m a bit lost apart from this

Comment: As ideals, the GCD is $\langle X,Y\rangle$,. But as elements of the UFD, $k[X,Y]$, the GCD is $1$. Two different things.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What is $\langle X,Y\rangle$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As elements, $X$ and $Y$ are both prime since $K[X,Y]/(X) \cong K[Y]$ which is a domain for instance.  So $X$ and $Y$ are both irreducible and must have gcd 1.

This stronger property than just being a GCD domain that you suggest, that $(a,b)=(gcd(a,b))$ is called a Bezout Domain, where all finitely generated ideals are principal.  Every PID is obviously a Bezout Domain.  So I suppose this would be an argument for why $K[X,Y]$ is not a PID, but is still a UFD.

Comment: But if the GCD is 1 can't I find $f$ and $g$ so that $1=f\cdot X+g\cdot Y$ and hence $(X,Y)=k[X,Y]$?

Comment: Ah, that is a different property.  That is called a Bezout domain.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout_domain